# Tab based application with TableView and Navigation Controller using Xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I want to create a Tableview in a Tab bar application.
Because I'm using the new version of Xcode (Xcode 4.2) I cannot view the "MainWindow.xib" to place a navigation controller there. I have viewed another question where it said to insert the following code in "App Delegate.m"

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
UITableViewController *viewController3 = [[ParkTable alloc] initWithNibName:@"ParkTable" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController4 = [[TableView alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableView" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController1 [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController4]];

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.ParkTableDel = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];

self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, viewController3, viewController4, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;    
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

I inserted this code an received an error stating "Size of array has non-integer type 'UINavigationController *'

I was wondering if anyone could tell me what i have done, and/or point me towards a tutorial that shows how to insert a TableView with navigation controller into a tab based application programatically or a tutorial showing how to get the "mainWindow.xib" in Xcode 4.2.

Any Help would be appreciated as I have hit a brick wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work. You just forgot a '='.

Try this:

```
UINavigationController *navController1 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController4]];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried entering this line of code and i get an error stating "Expected Identifier"

Answer (score 2):

You've got to many brackets:

```
UINavigationController *navController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
```

EDIT:

and instead of adding the viewController4, add the navController1.
(This one has the viewController4 in it)

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, viewController3, navController1, nil];
```